# Adding form to multiple pages

Tags: cognito-forms, wordpress

I have two WordPress sites that are for the same organization. One is members only and one is for the public. They are using the same top level domain. The member site adds the extension / members. I would like to put some of my forms on both sites, but it doesn't seem possible. The form names do not appear in my plugin selection list. I've also tried inserting the embed code directly on the page (on the text editor side). The form does not appear.